# read the variable from a matrix and use them in a function in R?

Tags: r

I have a 682*1 matrix called "met" , the first 5 rows similar below:

```
>  rownames(met)[1:5]

    [1]  "glycine_imp" 
    [2]  "Nacetylglycine_imp" 
    [3]  "sarcosine_imp"      
    [4]  "dimethylglycine_imp" 
    [5]  "betaine_imp"
```

and I have a function in R that each time use one of the row names of "met" matrix and create a new object file and I should save the objects!

```
my function is  
prep[i]<- Scores(Z=GT,formula="met[i]~egfr_v1_ckdepi+pc1+pc2+pc3+V1AGE01+GENDER")
```

Each time I just should change the met[i] and replace it by row names of "met" matrix( one by one) and for each of them I should change the name of the function and after that I should save each object!

for example for first row of "met" I have "glycine_imp"

```
>   **prep1**<- Scores (Z=GT,formula="**glycine_imp**~egfr_v1_ckdepi+pc1+pc2+pc3+V1AGE01+GENDER") 
    #creat the object file for first row and called prep1###

>   save(prep1, file="prep1.RData", compress="bzip2")
    ##save the object file as "prep1.RData"#####
```

I should do this process for 682 row names of "met" matrix and at the end I should have
"prep1.RData"  ,   "prep2.RData"   , "prep3.RData"

I use loop function but it has different errors!!
would you please what should I do?

Comment: This is not at all clear. You seem to be think that `met[i]` should be somehow referencing the rownames? This would require us being able to see the code in your `Scores` function to offer any advice. I'll hold off voting to close but if you don't address the lack of clarity I will vote in an hour or so to close.

Comment: You also should not cross post to SO and r-help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of your functions, so I can only provide a broad idea.

```
A <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 5)
Scores <- function(x){return(x+1)}

for(i in 1:10){
  df <- data.frame(tmp = 1)
  name <- paste("prep", as.character(i), sep = "") 
  df[[name]]=Scores(A)
  save(file = paste("prep", as.character("i"), ".RData", sep = ""), df[[name]], 
       compress = "bzip2")
}
```

Does that work?